# jaxb2-maven-plugin - how to turn off recursive directory traversal when generating xsd from classes

Tags: java, maven, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin, schemagen

I am using jaxb2-maven-plugin for generating XSD from jaxb annotated classes.

The configuration looks like that

```
<execution>
    <id>rest-api-execution-schemagen</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>schemagen</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <sources>
            <source>src/java/foo/rest/execution/model</source>
        </sources>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/execution-api-xml-schema</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

The package foo/rest/execution/model contains many classes, that is why I wish to avoid listing all of them in separate `<source>` elements. Instead, I specified that I wish to include the whole `src/java/foo/rest/execution/model` directory, using a single `<source>` element.

The problem is that there are subpackages:

```
foo/rest/execution/model/builder
```

... which contain other classes that are not jaxb annotated and should not be part of the schema.
Unfortunately, the schemagen goal attempts to traverse the foo/rest/execution/model directory recursively and therefore attempts to generate schemas for the classes in the subdirectories.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xjcSourceExcludeFilters` to filter the sources defined by `source` i.e. to exclude packages, files etc.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <sources>
        <source>src/java/foo/rest/execution/model</source>
    </sources>
    <xjcSourceExcludeFilters>
        <filter implementation="org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.shared.filters.pattern.PatternFileFilter">
            <patterns>
                <pattern>src/java/foo/rest/execution/model/builder/*.java</pattern>
            </patterns>
        </filter>
    </xjcSourceExcludeFilters>
    ...
</configuration>
```

If the built-in [filter support](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/filters.html) cannot meet your needs then you can provide your own implementation by replacing `org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.shared.filters.pattern.PatternFileFilter` with your own implementation of `AbstractFilter`.

More details on using this [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html) and more details on defining filters [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/filters.html).

Comment: The pattern <pattern>src/java/foo/rest/execution/model/builder/*.java</pattern> doesn't work unfortunately :(
I guess the syntax is wrong.

Comment: You might need to read [the docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/filters.html) and play around with filter patterns or just provide your own implementation of `AbstractFilter`.

Comment: I believe pattern is a regex, not a fileglob pattern.  So you would need something like  `builder/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.java`